# Termios and opening files

Tags: c, file, uart, termios

I need to "talk" with a certain sensor through a UART connection. 
Using the termios everything works with no problems and I'm able to have continuous communications with it- writing and reading multiple times.

But if I open a file for r/w purposes using either `fopen()` or `open()` at any time during this communication, the UART connection stops working properly:
messages can still be sent, but when read they're incomplete.
Even closing and reopening the same UART connection results in errors.
Code is written in C, and am currently using Eclipse on some Linux distro. All of this on VM.

Any ideas on what could cause this problem?

P. S.: any suggestions regarding posting here would also be appreciated

Comment: Post what you code so far.

Comment: "But if I open a file using either fopen() or open() ..." : What file? a different one, or one referencing the tty that corresponds to the serial device?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using the same BAUD rate which your sensor works on. This is is the main problem most of the times.